# R Left join and display average airplanes delay airports

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm working on Hadley Wickams book "R 4 Data Science", Chapter 13. It asks to calculate and visualize the average delay of flights at various airports throughout the US.

Initial operations to setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
```

This makes 5 tables available `flights`, `planes`, `airports`, `airlines` and `weather`.
I calculate the average delay per destination (omitting `NA` values, is that ok?):

```
flights2 <- flights %>% group_by(dest) %>%
                        summarise(avg=mean(dep_delay, na.rm=T)) %>%
                        left_join(airports, c("dest"="faa"))
flights2 %>%
            ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) + geom_point(aes(size=avg)) + 
                                    borders("states") +
                                    coord_quickmap()
```

Are my averages correct?
All circles in the map are more less equally large, how can I make them better distinguishable?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more like how to make the points more apparent using `ggplot2`. I believe we can use the `trans_new` function from the `scales` package to define a transformation and apply that transformation to the size scale.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(scales)

# The same analysis yu did
flights2 <- flights %>% group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(avg=mean(dep_delay, na.rm=T)) %>%
  left_join(airports, c("dest"="faa"))

# Use trans_new function from the scale package to define the square transformation
sq_trans <- function(){
  trans_new(name = "sq", 
            transform = function(x) x^2, 
            inverse = function(x) sqrt(x))
  }

# Plot the data 
flights2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) + 
  # Use alpha to make overlaid points apparent
  geom_point(aes(size = avg), colour = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  # Apply the sq transformation
  scale_size(range = c(1, 6), trans = "sq")
```

#### Note

Notice that you can test different number in `range = c(...)` along without any transformation, but I did not find a good values for that, so I just used the default. In the `trans` argument, there are many other transformation we can choose, such as `log`, `log10`, `sqrt` ... (See `?scale_size` for more information). Again, I did not find a good transformation so I decided to define the square transformaton, which is size = avg^2. Please see `?trans_new` to learn how to define new transformation.

Finally, because there are lots of points overlaid together, we can use `alpha = ...` to specify the transparency of points, making each point more clear.

#### Update

To show more size classes, we can set `breaks` in `scale_size` to specify the break points.

```
# Plot the data 
flights2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat)) + 
  # Use alpha to make overlaid points apparent
  geom_point(aes(size = avg), colour = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  # Set break points in 5, 10, 20, 30; Apply the sq transformation
  scale_size(breaks = c(5, 10, 20, 30), trans = "sq")
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Maybe even a first starting point would be to just have more levels? So not just 10, 20, 30, but finer granulation? How could that be done? Btw., i think differnet scales (log10, exp, ...) can be directly applied to the `avg` value in the `aes` call to in `geom_point`. But definietly, the circles are now more different from eachother.

Comment: If you do the transformation directly to `geom_point`, such as `geom_point(aes(size = avg^2))` The numbers in the legend would change, from about `10 - 30` to `250 - 1250`. This is the reason why I think it is necessary to do transformation in `scales_size`. The only thing I want to change is point area, not numbers.

Comment: Please see my updates. I have shown how to use `breaks` to define more size classes if this is what you want.